# Text automatically scrolling downward on Android

Tags: android

Does anyone know of a good way for text to appear on the screen scrolling vertically downward from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the full-on Star Wars crawl with the perspective or just regular text blocks moving down the screen?

Here are a few HTML/CSS examples of the full Star Wars Crawl effect:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/star-wars-html-and-css-a-new-hope

http://forrst.com/posts/Starwars_Opening_Crawl-vr5

Comment: regular text blocks moving down the screen please. Sorry if my question was confusing. Not tilted like star wars, however it should be continually moving downward